# Opinion dynamics in Netlogo

Tags: probability, netlogo

I have just discovered netlogo as a tool for modelling social processes. I need help for implementing a model I would like to test.

In my model, I have two types of agents, either angry or fearful. 
Angry ones have a "risky" opinion between 6 and 10
Fearful ones have a "moderate" opinion between 1 and 5

They may change their opinion under the influence of their Moore neighbours, according to this rule:

```
to compute-influence
  ask turtles
  [ ask one-of turtles
    [ set opinion ( sum [ opinion ] of turtles-on neighbors ) / count turtles-on neighbors

      set opinion precision ( influencedOpinion) 1
      set steps steps + 1

      ifelse opinion < 6
       [ set opinion "moderate" ]
       [ set opinion "risky" ]
    ]
  ]
  recolor-turtles
end
```

What I would like to do is modelling a different behaviour of angry and fearful agents, so that both follow the rule, but:

- fearful agents update their opinion according to the rule with a probability of 65%
- angry agents with a probability of 35%

Probably because of my inexperience, I did not find in the Netlogo manual anything about applying a probability to a rule...can anyone help?

thanks,
benedetta

Comment: `random-float 1 < 0.35` reports `true` 35% of the time.

Comment: seems in your question you state opinion is a numerical value, but in your ifelse statement you change it to a string.

Comment: Every agent has a numerical value as opinion, but if their opinion lies between 1 and 5 they are considered "moderate" (and colored blue); if they have an opinion between 6 and 10 are considered "aggressive" (and colored red). (sorry, I should have stated that before)

Comment: I have tried this, but I have to split the code in two comments becasue I cannot format code here: 'to compute-influence-social-network
  ask turtles
  [ ifelse ( random-float 1 <= 0.35 )
  [ ask turtles with [ opinion = "aggressive"]
    [ set influencedOpinion ( sum [ influencedOpinion ] of turtles-on neighbors ) / count turtles-on neighbors ]
  ]  [ ask turtles with [ opinion = "moderate" ]
  [ set influencedOpinion ( sum [ influencedOpinion ] of turtles-on neighbors ) / count turtles-on neighbors ]
  ]
  ]

Comment: set influencedOpinion precision ( influencedOpinion) 1

      ifelse influencedOpinion < 6
       [ set opinion "moderate" ]
       [ set opinion "risky" ]
  recolor-turtles
end' However, I get an error that I cannot use the tick in the go procedure because it is an observer variable only. I do not understand why.

Comment: Sorry, cannot read this unformatted code. You can edit your existing question to include corrected, formatted code, or you can open a new question.

Comment: @Seth, I have solved my problem. I posted another question for further problems.